# Delete trigger is fired when 0 rows are affected

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am using SQL Server and have a issue with delete trigger, because it's fired when there are 0 rows affected(deleted) and i want that it's fire when one row is affected(deleted).

This happen because i am using CASCADE

Comment: Add a test at the front of your trigger: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) BEGIN`

Comment: Thanks,I will try this, but is this the only solution?

Comment: Just to clarify "i want that it's fire when one row is affected" - you're not going to get that either. Triggers fire *per statement*. `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. A well-written trigger copes with *all* of those situations.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql):

> triggers fire when any valid event is fired, regardless of whether or
>   not any table rows are affected.

Laughing Vergil has given you the solution in his comment.